# klist -li 0x3e7 help needed

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

Trying to renew computer group membership without restarting by issuing klist -li 0x3e7 from an elevated command prompt, but it's not working. Klist returns tickets flushed, but a gpresult still shows the old group memberships.

Answer (score 1):

The complete command to purge is as below.

```
klist -li 0x3e7 purge
```